# Find the distance between two sets

Tags: general-topology

I need to find the distance between the two following sets and prove it.
 [image]

I wanted to prove that $d(A,B)=\sqrt5-1$ and I was able to prove only that $d(A,B)\le\sqrt5-1$ as detailed below:

[image]

Where $a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n},0\right)$ and $b_n=\left(\sqrt5+\frac{1}{n},0\right)$

Can someone please help me with the other side?

Comment: Note that the $\frac1n$ do *not* cancel out: they have opposite signs. $(1-\frac1n) - (\sqrt 5+\frac1n)= 1-\sqrt 5 - \frac2n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by contradiction $d(A,B)<\sqrt{5}-1$. Then you can find $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $d(a,b)<\sqrt{5}-1$. By triangle inequality, $d((0,0),b)\leq d((0,0),a)+d(a,b)<\sqrt{5}$. Thus, $b\notin B$, a contradiction.